# Reading a file in Java with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I'm trying to get a program to read a text file but it's throwing a FileNotFoundException even though I have the potato.txt file set in the project directory.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String potato = "potato.txt"; // assume this line can't be changed at all

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(potato)); // throws FileNotFoundException

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Where is your file exactly?

Comment: Try using the absolute path.

Comment: please post project structure

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full Path, like this:

```
File file = new File("C:/temp/potato.txt"); //This is just an example path, look up your files path and put it here.
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
```

Also, don't forget to close your scanner when done (after your `while`-loop):

```
scan.close();
```

Comment: I have it set like that and set the file path to ("C:/Users/The Turd 9000/workspace/IOTutorial/potato.txt"). I got that from using getabsolutepath(); and it is still giving me the same FileNotFoundException on the Scanner line.

Comment: Edit in your project structure and full error message in your question, so I can look at that please.